# Error in apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I'have `Ubuntu 14.04`  , if i do : `sudo apt-get update`
the result  is :

```
    Ign http://ftp.debian.org wheezy InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]           
Get:2 http://ftp.debian.org wheezy Release.gpg [2,373 B]                       
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
Ign http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy Release                                       
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15.4 kB]                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                               
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      
Ign http://ftp.debian.org wheezy Release                                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                   
Ign http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main Sources/DiffIndex                        
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [110 kB]         
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Ign http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex                  
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-en                           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                    
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [4,035 B]  
Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main Sources                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex              
Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main amd64 Packages                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex               
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                        
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [34.7 kB]    
Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main i386 Packages                            
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [2,750 B]  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [448 kB]  
Ign http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-en_US                        
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US                
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [13.0 kB]
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [126 kB]
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4,991 B]
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [422 kB]  
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages            
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                   
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en            
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Hit http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en              
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                          
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [12.7 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [126 kB]
Ign http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [5,175 B]
Ign http://dz.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Fetched 1,392 kB in 12s (115 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ftp.debian.org wheezy Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY 6FB2A1C265FFB764
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B5B116B72D0F61F0
```

what is the problem ? and how resolved  this problem ?
the problem is :

> W: GPG error: http://ftp.debian.org wheezy Release: The following
>   signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
>   available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010
>   NO_PUBKEY 6FB2A1C265FFB764
>       W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
>   not available: NO_PUBKEY B5B116B72D0F61F0

Comment: http://ccm.net/faq/809-debian-apt-get-no-pubkey-gpg-error

Comment: W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B5B116B72D0F61F0
W: GPG error: http://ftp.debian.org wheezy Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY 6FB2A1C265FFB764
You have new mail in /var/mail/root

Answer (score 1):

Try: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <missing_key>`

Comment: Also, for readers, you should independently verify key fingerprints such as this one, before adding them to your system.

Comment: Agreed! Keys should be verified. So long as the user is aware of the package they are installing, if they encounter "key cannot be verified" message, they can add it.